# UTF-8 encoding issue

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to fetch data from rss feed (feed location is   http://www.bgsvetionik.com/rss/  ) in c# win form. Take a look at the following code:

```
public static XmlDocument FromUri(string uri) 
     {

        XmlDocument xmlDoc;
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        using (Stream rssStream = webClient.OpenRead(uri))
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(rssStream);
            xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.XmlResolver = null;
            xmlDoc.Load(reader);
        }
        return xmlDoc;
   }
```

Although xmlDoc.InnerXml contains XML definition with UTF-8 encoding, I get `&scaron;` instead of š etc.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The feed's data is incorrect. The `&scaron;` is inside a [CDATA section](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp), so it isn't being treated as an entity by the XML parser.

If you look at the source XML, you'll find that there's a mixture of entities and "raw" characters, e.g. `či&scaron;ćenja` in the middle of the first title.

If you need to correct that, you'll have to do it yourself with a `Replace` call - the XML parser is doing exactly what it's meant to.

EDIT: For the replacement, you *could* get hold of all the HTML entities and replace them one by one, or just find out which ones are actually being used. Then do:

```
string text = element.Value.Replace("&scaron;", "š")
                           .Replace(...);
```

Of course, this means that anything which is actually *correctly* escaped and should *really* be that text will get accidentally replaced... but such is the problem with broken data :(

Comment: @Jon Skeet  Great answer; you just beat me to it ;-).  Pardon my doing a bit of SO.meta, here (we can remove these comments in a few minutes), but I'm wondering why you reply in community wiki.  I'm new to SO and would like to know the difference / accepted practice in this area.

Comment: If it wasn't in a CDATA section would it not simply error anyway since XML has no idea what that entity refers to? As far as I was aware XML only understand a very limited subset of entities that work in HTML.  Its not uncommon for RSS feeds to abuse the description element by including html content in the description.

Comment: +1, it's what Hanselman calls "angle-bracket-delimited" data and not XML at all. BTW any reason why this is community wiki?

Comment: Thanks Jon! So, the only way to solve it is to make some Replacer() method which would replace all data from CDATA section?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I haven't checked whether the entity is being declared or not - but yet, I agree it's probably just a badly written feed. @mvj/MarkJ: I'm having a "rep holiday" until Monday, making all my posts CW. Pay no attention to that :)

Comment: There are no entities declared anywhere in feed document. Furthermore, it is declared to be in windows-1250 encoding (in the xml declaration)

Comment: @VoidPointer: Not sure what feed you were looking at but there were definitely entities in the feed I looked at.